# General performance of objects vs dictionary from/into JSON

Tags: c#, .net, performance, object, dictionary

I am using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for converting into JSON which i use for data transfer between server and client.

And i wanted to ask you if is there some big difference in performance during serialization and deserialization and if not what about general performance in application ?

Is work with object faster then dictionaries? I mean reading variables, getting values on some indexes in arrays etc. Or is +- same?

Comment: Accessing data on a dictionary will perform a search on the keys, when you use an object's property the access is direct. With low element count the difference will be small but if there are a lot of properties it will be noticeable.

Comment: Once you include the time required to generate dictionaries from objects, any speed difference will disappear. Your code though will be unreadable

Comment: @Gusman About how many elements are we talking? dozens? hundreds? Because i am not using more than 10-15 elements.

Comment: That's relative, if you have 10 elements and you access them thousands of times it will be noticeable, if you have hundreds of elements then it also will be noticeable, but at the end it depends on how you will use it. Anyway, for my experience is better to use objects because you have a perfectly predefined structure for your data what has benefits not only in performance but in code readability and maintenance. But that's just an opinion, the only one who can decide about it is you as you know the real usage case.

Comment: @Gusman I have to access them just one time practically, to read data which i received and thats all. Objects sounds better but dictionaries are more friendly while adding some new data information in the same answer.

Comment: Honestly, the time taken to serialise is pretty insignificant compared to data transmission

Comment: you can measure time for both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some test, it takes 5 sec on my computer to serialize and deserialize 1 000 000 simple, not nested objects.
With dictionary it takes around 4 sec, so it does not really matter.

I would recommend use of objects due to their flexibility. Retrieving value from dictionary by indexers in .NET will always be O(1).

```
    public void TestSerialization()
    {
        var loops = 1000000;

        var w1 = new Stopwatch(); w1.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            var serializedDic = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Color", "Blue" }, { "Price", "5" } });
            var deserializedDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedDic);
        }
        w1.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(w1.Elapsed); //4.37 sec

        var w2 = new Stopwatch(); w2.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            var serializedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CarObj() { Color = "blue", Price = 5 });
            var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedObj);
        }
        w2.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(w2.Elapsed); //5.57 sec
    }

    public class CarObj
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by flexibility? In my case the dictionary are much more flexible i think. If i wanted to add another parameter into my JSON message i can just simple add another key, but in case of object i have to rewrite the class. And what about deserialization how can i find the right class where my json objects below? What if you define another class Car where will be int instead of float. what data type will `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedObj)` be?

Comment: question 1: more flexible because you can have nested objects, so you can easily extend informations you want to manipulate with. I don't think there is simple way how to do this with dictionaries, question 2: you can specify type of result object from deserialization in json .net like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedDic, typeof(CarObj))